# Make a disk sleep permanently

Tags: boot, hard-drive, suspend, disk

On my computer I have 3 hard disks with 3 different OSes, but one of those disks it's a little bit old and I want to make it sleep always, because it consumes power and makes noise, but I'm not even using it!

I tried with the Disk Utility GUI, but it doesn't do anything.
Also tried with hdparm.conf, just by adding my device and "sleep" on a new entry, it works, it makes sleep the hard disk, but when ubuntu loads up, the disk wakes up again.

Can I make a "permanent" sleep ONLY for this hard disk drive?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't prevent it from starting when you boot up the computer.

Comment: Well, I don't say at BIOS boot time, I say, when linux kernel boots up and has all services loaded.

Comment: @user261711, the bios loads before linux does, so the disk is already spun up.  In fact, ata disks spin up the moment power is applied, unless you enable power up in standby, usually via a jumper, but both the typical system bios, and the linux kernel have to spin up most disks in order to identify them.